# Pythonic way to get the greatest value with the same index from different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict of lists like the following:

```
{
    'FR-8_20190502_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190505_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7418],
    'FR-8_20190507_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190509_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7384],
    'FR-8_20190508_MD_Case1': [12948, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190506_MD_Case1': [12056, 8250, 13023, 7223]
}
```

And I would like to have a list of the greatest values of each index of these lists, for example:

```
[12948, 8250, 13023, 7418]
```

Here is what I have so far, it works but I am pretty sure it can be improved: (`ima_sizes` is my dict of lists)

```
max_sizes = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for k, v in ima_sizes.items():
    for i in range(4):
        if v[i] > max_sizes[i]:
            max_sizes[i] = v[i]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to achieve that?

Comment: You don't seem to care about the keys at all, so `[max(vals) for vals in ima_sizes.values()]`?

Comment: It doesn't give the desired output but `[13023, 13023, 13023, 13023, 13023, 13023]`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant; you need to add a zip to transpose, as shown in Andrej's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `zip()` to transpose the values and `max()` to find maximum value:

```
d = {
    'FR-8_20190502_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190505_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7418],
    'FR-8_20190507_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190509_MD_Case1': [11595, 8250, 13023, 7384],
    'FR-8_20190508_MD_Case1': [12948, 8250, 13023, 7223],
    'FR-8_20190506_MD_Case1': [12056, 8250, 13023, 7223]
}

print([max(v) for v in zip(*d.values())])
```

Prints:

```
[12948, 8250, 13023, 7418]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I did not think about using `zip()`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use numpy and have the list of list as numpy array, like

```
array = [[11595, 8250, 13023, 7223],
[11595, 8250, 13023, 7418],
....
[12056, 8250, 13023, 7223]]
```

Then you can use 
`numpy.amax(array,axis=0)` which will return an array of max elements at each column(along axis 0)

Comment: `numpy` seems like a good approach but I like Andrej Kesely's solution better, +1 though

Comment: that's pythonic way, and this is python frameworkic way. lol ! happy learning ! i agree that his answer should be the accepted answer.